# Does RequestServices.GetService() have a significant impact on performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is RequestServices.GetService() an expensive operation?  Is it a bad practice to use GetService() in a method if you cannot get services in the constructor?

Note: I am **not** asking if Dependency Injection is performant.  I am asking if using RequestServices.GetService() inside a method (where you can's use DI such as in a custom attribute) is a bad idea, or is it essentially equivalent in performance to 'normal' constructor based DI.

I am using a custom attribute in an Asp.Net MVC Core application.  In the OnAuthoizationAsync() method, I need to access a configuration setting.  As my class inherits from 'Attribute', I cannot use DI to pass an object into the constructor.  I am using the  HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService() method to get the instance of configuration.  The custom attribute could run on most requests, so it cannot have a big performance impact.

```
public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
   var config = (IConfiguration)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IConfiguration));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use normal dependency injection. Inject `IConfiguration` into the class constructor.

Comment: You can't use DI in the constructor for a custom attribute class.

Comment: Maybe a couple dictionary lookups. If the service is not found, or is transient, a pre-compiled factory method. The overhead shouldn't be too bad. Measure it if you're concerned. You might save more by using strong typed configuration.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The correct question is "am I having performance problems now using this method", and if the answer is "no" - which it almost always is - then **stop worrying about it**. Premature optimisation is the root of all wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method is run for (almost) every request, the dependency is also resolved at every request.

The cost of resolution is usually a non-issue, unless you're using a custom DI provider (Autofac) and have complex rules for type resolution. But Microsoft's DI purposefully keeps things simple, which speeds up type resolution.

Additionally, you might need to consider the dependency lifetime. If the type is added to DI as transient, it's allocated & created every time you resolve it (i.e. every time the method is executed)

If it's scoped, it's allocated once per request. So if the attribute is used multiple times, only a single object is created and returned when you resolve a type. So you pay the price once per request.

If it's singleton, it's allocated once per (app/DI container) lifetime, so you pay the price only once.

So if the type is large and slow to create, it might create some overhead, but you can avoid it by conditionally resolving it under some `if`s, for example.
All things considered, it's almost certainly a fraction of the time spent when doing IO, so I'd not worry about it.